# Trying to do a multiple grep in R with regular expressions

Tags: r, regex

I have to look for some registers with a regular expression in a massive log file with R.

All the data is about 1 Gb and i have to look for some registries and add the matches to a dataframe.

What I am doing is the following:

```
grep(paste("(Sending+.+message+.+1234567890+.+5000)", sep=""), dfLogs)
```

This goes correct when I do it for only one register.
When I try to do the grep for all the searches:

```
dfTrx$RcvMessage <- paste("(Sending+.+message+.+", dfTrx$NUMBER, "+.+", dfTrx$AMOUNT,")", sep="")
dfReceived <- unique(grep(paste(dfTrx$RcvMessage, collapse="|"), dfLogs), value=TRUE)
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error in grep(paste(dfTrx$RcvMessage, collapse = "|"), dfLogs) : 
  invalid regular expression '(Sending+.+message+.+1234567890+.+20)|(Sending+.+message+.+9876543210+.+20)|...
```

How can I do this regular expression for all the values? What am I doing wrong?

An example for data:

> 2015-12-09 19:01:44,717 - [DEBUG] [pool-1-thread-4450  ] [OutputHandler       ] Sending 8 message(s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

I need to find the sending of the message, and the number and amount in the content of the message.

Comment: Show some data. The matching strategy does not look very promising but cannot really offer constructive advice with out examples for testing.

Comment: ok, here is an example:
2015-12-09 19:01:44,717 - [DEBUG] [pool-1-thread-4450  ] [OutputHandler       ] Sending 8 message(s) : 2015-12-09 19:01:44,717 - [DEBUG] [pool-1-thread-4450  ] [OutputHandler       ] Sending 8 message(s) : 01XX765903091220151901440XXXX0000129D3A000039961019014420151209038576551847767334380000002000

Is too long, so i can't put all the 8 messages. What I want to find is the sent message with the number and amount needed. I already have the dates filtered.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question when giving new information. Don't post it in the comments.

Comment: Maybe one of `RcvMessage` is wrong? You could trace it down by: `for (i in 1:nrow(dfTrx)) grep(dfTrx$RcvMessage, "xyz")`. If error occure then `dfTrx$RcvMessage[i]` shows bad case.

Comment: ok, i'll try that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks at @Marek.
I found that in the df there were some bad values that were giving me NA and some spaces that I hadn't seen before. Seems I didn't clean all the data properly. Thanks and sorry for a silly mistake from me.